# Return a dictionary within a dictionary in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary

I want to return dictionary within a dictionary.I have the following code which constructs a dictionary in the following format:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>

Dictionary<string,string> Extdictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();

Extdictionary.Add("Source", myMessage.Src);
Extdictionary.Add("TimeStamp", myMessage.TimeStamp);
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> queExtractedDictionary = 
     new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

queExtractedDictionary.Add("Ext", Extdictionary);
```

and populates the values like

```
"Ext" "Key1" "Value1"
"Ext" "Key2" "Value2"

"Ext1" "Key1" "Value1"
"Ext1" "Key2" "Value2"
```

I want to access Key2(of "Ext") and change the value and then return Dictionary like

```
"Key1" "Value1"
"Key2" "New Value"
```

I am not too sure how to handle this code.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
queExtractedDictionary["Ext"]["Key2"] = "new value";
```

Breaking this down, `queExtractedDictionary["Ext"]` gets the `Dictionary` that is the value for the key "Ext". Then, you again access the key "Key2" of the returned `Dictionary`. Of course, you should check if the key exists and handle exceptions accordingly.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/BRJX42750)

Comment: Thanks.however I would first like to return the dictionary of key1 and value1 ,and then change the value.The reason is that I have a separate function which replaces value in dic<string,string>.however I am not able to extract dic<string,string> from dic<string, dic<string,string>>.

Comment: `queExtractedDictionary["Ext"]` is a `dic<string,string>`. You can just pass it to your function and treat it as a normal `Dictionary`. Is there something I am missing here?